# Flutter will no longer build on iOS with Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, emulation

new developer
I've been going through an online tutorial where when I get to the point I integrate Firebase my iOS emulator stops working. It does before, but not after. Additionally, there are no problems in my project according to flutter doctor and it even shows the iOS emulator as a connected device.

Things I have tried:

1. put GoogleService-Info.plist where it belongs
2. flutter clean
3. flutter update
4. pod init
5. pod update
6. I've recreated the project several times to this point and still can't get past this point

`Xcode build done.                                           174.6s Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳ ** BUILD FAILED ** Xcode's output: ↳ error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output CompileC /Users/new/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvilcmacwsblvfgwjiawkhcwbfpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mantle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EXTRuntimeExtensions.o /Users/new/IdeaProjects/explornation07/ios/Pods/Mantle/Mantle/extobjc/EXTRuntimeExtensions.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler /Users/new/IdeaProjects/explornation07/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:663:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized] (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length; ^~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/new/IdeaProjects/explornation07/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:595:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning int best_offset; ^ = 0 1 warning generated. /Users/New/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-0.6.8/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadataTIFF.m:42:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type] } ^ 1 error generated. note: Using new build system note: Building targets in parallel note: Planning build note: Using build description from disk Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode... Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation). Exited (sigterm)`

My only thought is maybe if I use a different emulator, but it works up until emulator. I don't know.

If needed, I can try to restart the project again from scratch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

please re-check your info.plist and your integration
if you checked everything is setup properly copy your lip and re integration your project and try again .. i think you misleading something
don't forget also check your packages versions

- and try to rm your profile and re install
  rm ios/Podfile